# Failed on reading Json iOS Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

I have written this code:

```
func json()
{
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.educaon.com.br/api/index.php/login?user=" + (username as String))!
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        print ("Task Completed")
        if let data = data
        {
            do
            {
                if let dict: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.SenhaJs = dict["SENHA"] as! String
                        self.IDJs = dict["ID"]as! Int
                        print (self.SenhaJs) //Resultado Esta Nulo
                    })
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

But after the `NSURLSession.sharedSession()` call, the application goes straight to `task.resume` and does not read the JSON.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What did you mean `not read the JSON`? The `dataTaskWithURL` method run and return result in other (background) thread, so, when you debug it step to `task.resume` is normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct for performing the network request and reading the JSON.

The problem may be with your URL. I tried a different URL

```
 let url = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=philip+glass")!
```

and was able to verify the results.

The URL that you are using is returning a JSON array and not a dictionary. Therefore, you have to change

```
if let dict: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

to

```
if let array: NSArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray
```

and handle the results as an array instead of a dictionary.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your support and sorry my bad English. The URL i'm trying to access is http://www.educaon.com.br/api/index.php/login?user=stocco. Can you see if there's a problem with the result of the URL?

Comment: Thanks, @LeandroLoli. Do you have App Transport Security configured in your Info.plist to handle the non-https URL?

Comment: This one?<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>yourserver.com</key>
            <dict>
               <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
              <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

Comment: Dammit!! It works... Really Really Thank you, Daniel